# How to reformat numbers into dates when it works individually but when script is used on all rows in R?

Tags: r, date

my date column from a dateframe

```
DateCol|OthCol|OthCol2
 44105    valu    valu
 44112  value2  value2
 44119  Value3  Value3
```

When I run each row individually I get the proper value which is "2020-10-08"

```
as.Date(44112,origin="1899-12-30") so the result for this should be October 1, 2020
```

When i run all the rows at once as the same code

```
as.Date(df$DateCol, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

I get the error message

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Are your numbers actually numbers? Or text? Make sure that your `DateCol` is actually numeric. Check what `str(df)` gives you. If it says DateCol is chr, there is your problem. Run `as.Date("44112",origin="1899-12-30")`. You will see you get the same error.

Comment: Also, that looks like an Excel date. You can use `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date()` and not worry about the origin, though again, this requires numeric not character. The function gives you that error though more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format` - supposing your dataframe is called `df`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(DateCol = c(44105, 44112, 44119))
```

Solution:

```
df$DateCol <- format(as.Date(df$DateCol, origin="1899-12-30"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Result:

```
df
     DateCol
1 2020-10-01
2 2020-10-08
3 2020-10-15
```

Comment: I don't want to create a seperate vector. I just want to pull the dates from the dataframe and leave them in there.

Comment: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: I think i need to change it to numeric and then run it through your function. I''ll try that.

Comment: Sorry, please try again (I'd forgotten to change a piece from the first code)

Comment: df$DateCol <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(df$DateCol ), origin="1899-12-30"), "%Y-%m-%d")